# Sending multi dimensional array from javascript to PHP

Tags: javascript, php

Hi I am struggling with this.

I have a javascript array that I send to PHP via a $POST using :

```
jsonScrutineeringArray = JSON.stringify(scrutineeringArray);
```

in PHP I do :

```
$jsonScrutineeringArray = $_REQUEST["jsonScrutineeringArray"];
$tempData = html_entity_decode($jsonScrutineeringArray);
$jsonScrutineeringArray2 = json_decode($tempData);
echo json_encode($jsonScrutineeringArray2);
for ($ii = 0; $ii < count($jsonScrutineeringArray2); ++$ii) {
    echo 'driverID ='.$jsonScrutineeringArray2['driverID'][$ii];
}
```

The result of the first echo is:

```
[{"ID":0,"driverID":"1","event":"Silverstone 21\/2\/2015","race":"Race2","FRTagID":"11","FRDepth":"11","FRNotes":"11","FRFail":"Fail","FLTagID":"22","FLDepth":"22","FLNotes":"22","FLFail":"Fail","RRTagID":"33","RRDepth":"33","RRNotes":"33","RRFail":"Fail","RLTagID":"44","RLDepth":"44","RLNotes":"44","RLFail":"Fail"},{"ID":0,"driverID":"2","event":"Silverstone 12\/3\/2015","race":"Race4","FRTagID":"22","FRDepth":"22","FRNotes":"22","FRFail":"Fail","FLTagID":"33","FLDepth":"33","FLNotes":"33","FLFail":"Fail","RRTagID":"44","RRDepth":"44","RRNotes":"44","RRFail":"Fail","RLTagID":"55","RLDepth":"55","RLNotes":"55","RLFail":"Fail"}]
```

So I am presuming that I have a correctly formed array in PHP.

However I am unable to echo the individual fields using variations of :

```
echo 'driverID ='.$jsonScrutineeringArray2['driverID'][$ii];
```

What am I missing here ?

Thanks.

Update. If I use var_dump($jsonScrutineeringArray2);

I get :

```
array(3) {
[0]=>
object(stdClass)#2 (20) {
["ID"]=>
int(1)
["driverID"]=>
string(1) "1"
["event"]=>
string(0) ""
["race"]=>
string(0) ""
["FRTagID"]=>
string(0) ""
["FRDepth"]=>
string(0) ""
["FRNotes"]=>
string(0) ""
["FRFail"]=>
string(0) ""
["FLTagID"]=>
string(0) ""
["FLDepth"]=>
string(0) ""
["FLNotes"]=>
string(0) ""
["FLFail"]=>
string(0) ""
["RRTagID"]=>
string(0) ""
["RRDepth"]=>
string(0) ""
["RRNotes"]=>
string(0) ""
["RRFail"]=>
string(0) ""
["RLTagID"]=>
string(0) ""
["RLDepth"]=>
string(0) ""
["RLNotes"]=>
string(0) ""
["RLFail"]=>
string(0) ""
}
[1]=>
object(stdClass)#3 (20) {
["ID"]=>
int(1)
["driverID"]=>
string(1) "1"
["event"]=>
string(21) "Silverstone 21/2/2015"
["race"]=>
string(5) "Race2"
["FRTagID"]=>
string(2) "11"
["FRDepth"]=>
string(0) ""
["FRNotes"]=>
string(0) ""
["FRFail"]=>
string(4) "Fail"
["FLTagID"]=>
string(3) "111"
["FLDepth"]=>
string(0) ""
["FLNotes"]=>
string(0) ""
["FLFail"]=>
string(4) "Fail"
["RRTagID"]=>
string(4) "1111"
["RRDepth"]=>
string(0) ""
["RRNotes"]=>
string(0) ""
["RRFail"]=>
string(4) "Fail"
["RLTagID"]=>
string(5) "11111"
["RLDepth"]=>
string(0) ""
["RLNotes"]=>
string(0) ""
["RLFail"]=>
string(4) "Fail"
}
[2]=>
object(stdClass)#4 (20) {
["ID"]=>
int(2)
["driverID"]=>
string(1) "2"
["event"]=>
string(21) "Silverstone 12/3/2015"
["race"]=>
string(5) "Race3"
["FRTagID"]=>
string(2) "22"
["FRDepth"]=>
string(0) ""
["FRNotes"]=>
string(0) ""
["FRFail"]=>
string(4) "Fail"
["FLTagID"]=>
string(3) "222"
["FLDepth"]=>
string(0) ""
["FLNotes"]=>
string(0) ""
["FLFail"]=>
string(4) "Fail"
["RRTagID"]=>
string(4) "2222"
["RRDepth"]=>
string(0) ""
["RRNotes"]=>
string(0) ""
["RRFail"]=>
string(4) "Fail"
["RLTagID"]=>
string(5) "22222"
["RLDepth"]=>
string(0) ""
["RLNotes"]=>
string(0) ""
["RLFail"]=>
string(4) "Fail"
}
}
```

So how do I loop through this please?

Comment: Try using `$jsonScrutineeringArray2[$ii]['driverID']`

Comment: Try simplifying it, use a foreach loop on the data and var_dump each step

Comment: web-nomad $jsonScrutineeringArray2[$ii]['driverID'] did not work

Answer (score 1):

You may try

```
foreach ($jsonScrutineeringArray2 as $jsonScrutineering) {
    echo 'Driver ID = ' . $jsonScrutineering->driverID;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
echo 'driverID ='.$jsonScrutineeringArray2['driverID'][$ii];
```

try this :

```
echo 'driverID ='.$jsonScrutineeringArray2[$ii]->driverID;
```

Comment: This worked okay echo 'driverID ='.$jsonScrutineeringArray2[$ii]->driverID;

Answer (score 0):

`json_decode($json, $assoc = false)` defaultly parse JS hash into standard object.
`$jsonScrutineeringArray2[$ii]->driverID`
Set the second parameter to ask for PHP associative array.
`$jsonScrutineeringArray2[$ii]['driverID']`

Also you made a mistake in the keys order.
`echo 'driverID ='.$jsonScrutineeringArray2[$ii]['driverID'];`
instead of
`echo 'driverID ='.$jsonScrutineeringArray2['driverID'][$ii];`